# Способы подписки на события

Tags: java, gwt

В GWT подписаться на события можно несколькими способами. В частности, существуют следующие методы: `addHandler(), addDomHandler(), addBitlessDomHandler()` и методы для конкретных событий.

Кроме того, на события можно подписаться с помощью методов `sinkEvents` и `onBrowserEvent`:

```
new SomeWidget() {
    {
        sinkEvents(Event.MOUSEEVENTS); // for example
    }

    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
        if (type == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
            ...
        } else if ...
    }
}
```

Если имеется не widget, а элемент, то можно подписаться на события так:

```
DOM.sinkEvents(element, Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
DOM.setEventListener(element, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
        if (type == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
            ...
        } else if ...
    }
});
```

В чем разница между этими способами? В каких случаях нужно использовать каждый из них? Каковы их недостатки и достоинства?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете о разнице между листенерами на элментах и хэндлерах на виджетах? Или между переопределением onBrowserEvent у виджета и листенером на елементе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае все объекты класса *SomeWidget* будут "по умолчанию" иметь слушатель *onBrowserEvent(Event event)* и срабатывать на установленный Вами *Event.MOUSEEVENTS*.
Во втором же случае, вышеперечисленные свойства будут относиться лишь к тем елементам, которые Вы укажете. Тоесть, в данном случае:

```
DOM.sinkEvents(someWidget1, Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
DOM.setEventListener(someWidget1, new EventListener() {

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
        if (type == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
            ...
        } else if ...
    }
});

DOM.sinkEvents(someWidget2, Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener(someWidget2, new EventListener() {

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
        if (type == Event.ONMOUSEDOWN) {
            ...
        } else if ...
    }
});
```

объекты *someWidget1* и *someWidget1* одного и того же класса, имеют разный *event*, в то время, как с использованием первого способа все объекты данного класса имели бы один и тот же *event*.

Надеюсь, что помог Вам.